# POST'ing JSON with Codeigniter returns a 500 error

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, json, codeigniter

I'm having trouble returning data from my controller using an ajax post function.  What happens here is the user will input a style number, submit that number to the controller.  The controller grabs the value submitted, queries the database and returns the results to the controller then the controller returns an array that I then encode into json.  But I keep getting a 500 Internal Server Error???

Here is my Controller

```
//return schools based on style id
public function search() {
    $input = json_decode($this->input->post('obj'));
    $style_id = $input['style_id'];
    $parent_id = $input['parent_id'];
    $data = array();
    if ($q = $this->page_model->search_results($style_id, $parent_id)) {
        $data = $q;
    }
    echo json_encode($data);
}
```

Here is my Model

```
//get all entries
function search_results($style_id, $parent_id) {
    $options = array(
        'Style' => $style_id,
        'Parent_ID' => $parent_id
    );
    $this->db->select('*');
    $this->db->from('pages');
    $this->db->join('entry', 'pages.Page_ID = entry.Parent_Page_ID', 'inner');
    $this->db->where($options);
    $q = $this->db->get();

    if ($q->num_rows() > 0) {
        return $q->result();
    }

}
```

Here is my javascript

```
//dress style search
$($searchBtn).click(function(event) {
    var style_id,
         parent_id,
         obj = {};
    //get the value of the input fields
    searchVal = event.currentTarget.previousSibling.value;
    parentID = event.currentTarget.parentElement.childNodes[3].value;
    //The object to be passed to the controller
    obj = { 'style_id' : searchVal, 'parent_id' : parentID };
    //POST the values in json notation, return the search results in json notation
    $.post(base_url + 'index.php/page/search',
            obj,
            function(data) {
                console.log(data);
            },
            'json');
    return false;
});
```

base_url=http://localhost:8888/lexsreg

BTW - If I comment out return false, I do get a json string echoed from my controller.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must include the csrf token.  There are a few ways to do this, as explained in these two blogs.

http://aymsystems.com/ajax-csrf-protection-codeigniter-20

http://codeigniter.com/forums/viewthread/176318/

Comment: In CI version 2.0.3the name of the csrf token changes yet again, and the name for this version is "csrf_test_name"

Answer (score 0):

Well, the first step is making sure that you're loaded `page_model`. Then I would make sure you're getting the right columns in the where clause -- do you need to identify those by `<table-name>.`?

Then basic CI debugging start with [log_message](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/errors.html): call `log_message('DEBUG', $this->input->post('obj'));` followed by `log_message('DEBUG', json_decode($this->input->post('obj')));`.

Comment: I'm autoloading my models, didn't know about the log_message function, I'll try that out thxs

Comment: figured out that i had to include the csrf token...d'oh!